# Are there meforshim on perek shira?

Tags: product-recommendation, animals, song-poetry, commentaries, perek-shira

Are there meforshim on perek shira? I'm looking for anything besides artscroll. If there are many, which would you recommend to start?

Comment: I would first recommend looking up all the pesukim in context.

Comment: You can find more if you search for "Perek Shirah" on HebrewBooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an archive of lots of shiurim on perek shira http://revach.net/avodah/perek-shira/19

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [*Perek Shirah: Nature's Song*](http://zootorah.com/books/songframe.html), by R' Natan Slifkin. He does a great job of explaining both what Perek Shirah is all about and what each element can teach us. He combines traditional commentaries on both Perek Shirah and its source verses with his knowledge of zoology and other natural sciences, and provides precise citations of all his sources to facilitate further study.

Answer (score 2):

[Braisa Perek Shira by Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky Shlita](http://hebrewbooks.org/49841)

[Perek Shira by Rabbi Yechiel Binyamin MiPlutzk Zatzal](http://hebrewbooks.org/22696)

Answer (score 1):

[Rav Yaakov Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden) wrote a commentary to Perek Shira entitled Zimrat Ha’arets, which is found in [his Siddur](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/42760).

[Mabit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Joseph_di_Trani) and [Hida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) also authored commentaries published together in a [single volume by Feldheim (2005)](http://www.feldheim.com/perek-shira-im-pirush-hamabit-v-hachida-hebrew-only.html).